# SQL convert string 3M to 3 month, 1Y to 1 year

Tags: php, mysql

I probably made a poor decision years ago where I have been storing intervals in a char(3) column with values such as "1M" or "3M" or "1Y". This helps me store info about recurring invoices. "1M" means the invoice renews every 1 month.

Here is a sample for the database : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WidX.png

The reason of this poor design is because I calculate the next invoice date through a php function :

```
function increment_date($date, $increment)
{
    $new_date = new DateTime($date);
    $new_date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $increment));
    return $new_date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

so that I can pass it arguments such as "P1M" which was actually very convenient for `DateInterval`

I now wish I stored them such as "1 month" instead of "1M", because I am stuck when try to run the following dynamic SQL request :

```
SELECT SUM(invoice_total) prevision_for_current_month
  FROM lf_invoice_amounts a
  JOIN lf_invoices_recurring r
    ON r.invoice_id a.invoice_id
 WHERE (month(recur_next_date) = 5 and year(recur_next_date)= 2020) 
    OR (month(recur_next_date - INTERVAL recur_frequency) = 5 and year(recur_next_date - INTERVAL recur_frequency) = 2020)
```

The part with `month(recur_next_date - INTERVAL recur_frequency)` fails and throws an error because it runs such as `month(recur_next_date - INTERVAL 1M)` which mySQL does not understand, while the following would have been correct : `month(recur_next_date - INTERVAL 1 month)`

The purpose of this sql request is to estimate all the money that should come in during current month, from invoices that are recurring every month/3 months/year/2 weeks/etc

I cannot refactor the whole code base at this moment. What would be a possible workaround?

TL;DR : How do I transform a column that contains value "1M" into "1 month" so that I can run SQL requests with intervals. (same for "3M" or "1Y" or "1M" or "2W" or "30D" or "31D", etc).
Ugly solutions also welcome. I'm currently think about a big nest of `replace()` maybe like `month(recur_next_date - INTERVAL replace(recur_frequency, 'M', ' month'))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately converting your `recur_frequency` into a string like `1 month` isn't going to help, as the syntax for [intervals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals) requires that `unit` be one of `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY` etc. i.e. one of a fixed set of specifiers, not a string, so trying to use something like `INTERVAL recur_frequency` or even `INTERVAL recur_frequency recur_period` won't work. Without using dynamic SQL to insert the value of `recur_frequency` into the query I think your best option is probably to store the recurrence frequency into one of 4 columns (e.g. `recur_year, recur_month, recur_week, recur_day`), then you can use a query such as

```
curdate() - interval recur_year year
          - interval recur_month month
          - interval recur_week week
          - interval recur_day day
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f5fbe3f3d1fc3483270b9784bfeaeff)